# how to print a row from the database using custom artisan command

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to fetch a row from a second database using a custom artisan command in Laravel. Now i want to print the result of the query but I keep getting an error. I would appreciate any help.

I setup the connection to **two databases** and they are connected and running without problems. the table that I am working with is called person and contains multiple columns such as **name, surname, person_id** (which is auto increment and primary key) and ssn. I also created a custom artisan command that fetches a row from the database when using

`php artisan import-users:DB 12345678`

and the query

`DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT * FROM person WHERE ssn=?', [$ssn])`

the result of the query is placed in the variable $user and now i just want to print it out but i keep getting errors. here is what i tried

```
$name = $user['name'];
```

which gives the

> ErrorException  : Undefined index: name

```
$this->line($user[0]);
```

which gives the

> ErrorException : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
$this->line($user->name);
```

which give the

> ErrorException  : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

I also tried many things but nothing worked. Thanks again

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class ImportUsers extends Command{

    protected $signature = 'import-users:DB {ssn}';
    protected $description = 'import users from old database';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $ssn = $this->argument('ssn');
        $user = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT * FROM person WHERE 
            ssn=?', [$ssn]);
        $this->line($user->name);
        $this->info($ssn.' Done');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of `$user`? (var_dump)

Comment: try `$this->line($user[0]->name)`

Comment: $this->line($user[0]->name) actually worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used like that

> ```
> for signle row
> ```

```
public function handle()
        {
            $ssn = $this->argument('ssn');
            $user = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT * FROM person WHERE 
                ssn=? limit 1', [$ssn]);

            if(isset($user[0])){
                 $this->line($user[0]->name); 
            }
            $this->info($ssn.' Done');
            $this->table($headers, $newUsers);
      }
```

> for multiple rows(array)

```
public function handle()
    {
        $ssn = $this->argument('ssn');
        $user = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT * FROM person WHERE 
            ssn=?', [$ssn]);
         //$userNameArray = [];  //if you want to show name in table 
         if(count($user) > 0) {
           foreach($user as $item)  {
              $this->line($item->name);
              //$userNameArray[] = $item->name;
            }
        } 

       $this->info($ssn.' Done');
       //$this->table(['Name'],$userNameArray); //optionall 
    }
```